# C# put variable in string with double quote inside code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make link inside code like this

```
"<href=officeclassification?id=" + this.office_id + "&classification=" + "" this.office_classification + ""+>"
```

office_classification contains 2 words like 
super used
super clean
the link in my page appear in this way

```
officeclassification?id=1&classification=super
```

but i want it to be

```
officeclassification?id=1&classification=super used
officeclassification?id=1&classification=super clean
```

how I can do that?

Comment: Why are you using double quotes incode? If your `office_classification` is a simple string, then just add it by `+`, what's the problem?

Comment: i would use a url builder to ensure things get encoded properly.

Comment: I want to pass classification in link and it contain more than one word, so I tried to put it in double quotes to pass the classification value but only first word was appeared in my link

Answer (score 1):

While the answers focussing on string.Format may make it easier to build the string, they don't address the issue of the space inside that `office_classification`.

For this you will need [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx), which is exposed in asp.net webforms as the `Server` property. This will encode problematic characters in a url-safe way.

```
string anchor = String.Format("<a href=\"officeclassification?id={0}&classification={1}\">", 
   this.office_id, 
   Server.UrlEncode(this.office_classification));
```

Comment: thnx for reply, I try it but it throws an exception with this.office_id :
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list
what is the problem?

Comment: Did you use the `{0}` placeholder for the first argument (office_id) and `{1}` for the second (office_classification)? You get this exception when you have a placeholder, but no argument. So either you provided less than two arguments or used a `{2}` (meaning 3rd arg) with just 2 args.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string.Format("officeclassification?id={0}&classification={1}", 
  this.office_id, this.office_classification)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string.Format("your text {0} and more text {1}", var1, var2)
```

{} are place holders for your variables you want to show in the string between double quotes above.

Say I want to say `"My dog {0} is {1} years old."`, I can use

```
string name = "Rufus";
int age 2;

Console.WriteLine("My dog {0} is {1} years old.", name, age);
```

, will print:

My dog Rufus is 2 years old.